# Is there a contradiction between the quran chapter 34 :44 and 14:37

Tags: quran, doubts, contradiction

Sahih International: And We had not given them any scriptures which they could study, and We had not sent to them before you, [O Muḥammad], any warner. Chapter 34:44

Sahih International: And those before them denied, and they [i.e., the people of Makkah] have not attained a tenth of what We had given them. But they [i.e., the former peoples] denied My messengers, so how [terrible] was My reproach. 34:45

Another translation

Mohsin Khan: And We had not given them Scriptures which they could study, nor sent to them before you (O Muhammad SAW) any warner (Messenger).

Mohsin Khan: And those before them belied; these have not received one tenth (1/10th) of what We had granted to those (of old), yet they belied My Messengers, then how (terrible) was My denial (punishment)!

The story of Prophet Ismail

Mohsin Khan:O Our Lord! I have made some of my offspring to dwell in a valley with no cultivation, by Your Sacred House (the Kaba at Makkah); in order, O our Lord, that they may offer prayers perfectly (Salah) so fill some hearts among men with love towards them, and O Allah provide them with fruits so that they may give thanks. O our Lord! Certainly, You know what we conceal and what we reveal. Nothing on the earth or in the heavens is hidden from Allah." (Surah Ibrahim 14:37-38)

Another translation

Sahih International: Our Lord, I have settled some of my descendants in an uncultivated valley near Your sacred House, our Lord, that they may establish prayer. So make hearts among the people incline toward them and provide for them from the fruits that they might be grateful.

Is there any contradiction between these two verses.

Please tell where prophet Ismail(PBUH) was send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ismail (AS) was the ancestor of Quraish. He wasn't a warner sent to them when they were lost in misguidance, nor did he have scripture he brought for them to read.

As such, there is no contradiction between the verses mentioned. The Prophet Muhammad (SAW) was the first ever warner sent to Quraish and more generally to the Arabs. In addition, the Quran was the first ever scripture given to them.

Comment: But isn't it said (I don't remember the verse) that Allah sent a messenger to every nation? That is, there must be a messenger to the Arabs before the Prophet, because then their polytheistic fathers died without warning. And about Ishmael: at 19:54 he is called a messenger. To whom, if not to the Arabs?

Comment: @Insan The possibility of some people dying without warning is not entirely negated. We have the concept of Ahlul-Fatrah.

Comment: But to whom was Ismail (a.s.) sent?

Comment: @Insan To his family. (19:55) And I don't think the fact that a distant ancestor of theirs was sent a prophet negates that those tribes at the time had not received a messenger before. Otherwise, might as well say everyone was sent a messenger because Adam and Nuh were their ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

I have only put as much as I know. The Qur'an doesn't contain any contradictions at all anywhere for it teaches:

"Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any] other than Allah , they would have found within it much contradiction” [an-Nisaa’ 4:82].

If one thinks The Qu'ran is contradicting then it's the individual's misunderstanding of that particular teaching.

And Allah knows best

Comment: Thank you brotheres

Comment: You're welcome. I am a sister though (no worries)

Comment: Ok sister thank you